# Generalized Hurwitz Zeta function

Tags: summation, zeta-functions

Let $d\ge 1$ be an integer, $a>0$ be a real number and let $\vec{s} := (s_0,\cdots,s_{d-1})$ where all the components are strictly bigger than one. We generalize the zeta function to higher dimensions as follows:
\begin{equation}
\zeta^{(d)} (\vec{s},a) := \sum\limits_{a \le l_{d-1} \le l_{d-2} \le \cdots \le l_0 < \infty}
\prod\limits_{\xi=0}^{d-1} l_\xi^{-s_\xi}
\end{equation}
Clearly $\zeta^{(1)}(s,a) = \zeta(s,a)$.
The question is can we compute the generalized function, to an arbitrary precision, using the zeta function and elementary functions only. 
Using the series representation of the zeta function (see Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function ) I have shown that the following expansion holds:
\begin{equation}
\zeta^{(2)}((s,s_1),a) = \frac{1}{s-1} \left[
\zeta(s+s_1-1,a) + \sum\limits_{q_1=1}^\infty \binom{1-s}{q_1} {\mathcal C}^{(2)}_{q_1} \zeta(s+s_1+q_1-1,a)\right]
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
{\mathcal C}^{(2)}_{q_1}  := \sum\limits_{m=1}^{q_1} \frac{1}{m+1}\sum\limits_{k=1}^m (-1)^k \binom{m}{k} k^{q_1}
\end{equation}

Now, the question is what is the corresponding expansion for arbitrary values of $d$?

Comment: Perhaps you are already aware of it, but you seem to want to generalize to the Hurwitz zeta the notion of Multiple zeta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function . Is it correct?